# How can I handle onclick event for bootstrap buttons?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an ajax call to fill a table with the results of a json response (I'm doing the call each time the user types on the textbox - keyup event handler), I can fill correctly the table but if I want to click the details button, the handler is doing nothing. I have tried different approach but none is working.

I have tried with both class and id selectors but none is working as expected.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

function getCustomerInfo(keyword) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/estimates/search/customer/" + keyword,
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      var row = "";
      row += "<table id='customersResult' class='table table-hover' style='border: 1px solid black'>";
      row += "<thead><th scope='col'>Id</th><th scope='col'>Name</th><th scope='col'>&nbsp;</th></thead>";
      row += "<tbody>";
      $.each(data,
        function (index, item) {
          row += "<tr id='customerRow' value=" + item.id + "><td scope='row'>" + item.id + "</td>";
          row += "<td>" + item.name + "</td>";
          row += "<td><button id='detailsCustomer' class='btn btn-success'>Details</button></td>";
          row += "<td><a href='http://www.google.com' id='fire' class='btn btn-success'>Details</a></td>";
          row += "</tr>";
        });
      row += "</tbody>";
      row += "</table>";
      $("#customers").html(row);
    },
    error: function (result) {
      alert("Error");
    }
  });
}

$("#fire").on('click',
  function(e) {
    alert('Pressing anchor');
  });

$("#detailsCustomer").on('click', function (e) {
  alert('Button was clicked...');
});

$("#txtCustomer").keyup(function () {
  getCustomerInfo($('#txtCustomer').val());
  console.log('key pressed: ' + $('#txtCustomer').val());
});

$("#customersResult").on('click', '.btn', function () {
  var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
  var currentCol = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text();

  alert('Button clicked...' + currentCol);
});

});
</script>

<input type="text" id="txtCustomer" name="CustomerName" class="form-control" style="width: 500px" />
<br />
<br />
<div id="customers">

</div>
```

I need to retrieve the Id which is in the first column in each row. I have no errors in console just it is doing nothing at all.

Comment: The reason is that your buttons will not exist when the events are hooked so will not be hooked to anything or if they are they will be overwritten by your AJAX calls success callback. I suggest using event delegation targeted at  `#customers` instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use delegated event handlers. Because your element is virtual  element.

```js
$("body").on('click', '#detailsCustomer', function (e) {
   alert('Button was clicked...');
});
```